# pH = 0 in pH layer

Tags: qgis, soilgrids, values

I have downloaded the pH layer from ISRIC database. However, when I added it to QGIS, I found it contained lots of points with the values = 0 (red points in picture).

Can I treat those 0 values as NA?

[image]

Comment: can you provide a link to the data you downloaded? most have metadata.

Comment: It's probably no data . But the only way to be sure is to look for metadata...

Comment: I used https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/phh2o.map in QGIS, and selected 15-30cm mean. I also downloaded the layer in R, it shows same problem. By the way, I used WCS to download the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used WCS to download the data is a known bug and ISRIC is working on solving it.

For pH it could be safe to consider the zeros as NA but it should not be done for other soil properties where zero is an acceptable value.

You can also download the data using a different approach, such as the ones suggested [here](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/soilgrids-access). At the bottom of the page you will find suggestions in python/R/bash on how to download a subset of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. May some of the zeros still be a bug for other soil properties by using WCS to download the relative data?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. We are working on solving the bug as soon as possible